# Undefined class constant 'PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_KEY' in/magento/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Model/ConfigOptionsList.php:179 in magento localhost

Tags: magento2, database, installation, php-7, magento2.3.4

**Ater execute any command getting this error**

> Operating system :- Mint ubuntu
>
> Php version  :- 7.2
>
> Magento :- 2.3.4[image]

Comment: Please refer this link :- https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/14660/files/3745fa8d08fe9e51fdcdb6053e2a54eeee254181

Answer (score 10):

Could make sure that you have installed the php-pdo and php-mysql packages?

Maybe you have different PHP versions installed. Check first which PHP version you are using

```
php --version
```

then install the packages for your PHP version. For example

```
apt-get install php7.4-pdo php7.4-mysql
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure this php extension is enabled:

```
extension=pdo_mysql
```

Comment: How to check if it is enabled?

Answer (score 0):

Backup and replace **Setup** folder on the root with already installed magento 2.* setup folder.

Then run the **php bin/magento setup:upgrade** and other.It will be fix.