# Magento 2.3.5 - freshly installed admin page is disabled and showing a spinner forever

Tags: magento2

After a fresh Magento 2.3.5 install, my admin dashboard is partially loaded. There is a spinning element that appears over it while the entire page is disabled. I have attached a picture. Please can someone tell me how I can solve this problem? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: you run all commands

Comment: @MohitPatel, which commands, please?

Comment: check my answer

Comment: Ok thanks @MohitPatel. Let me try.

Answer (score 0):

you are run all command like :-

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile    
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento c:f    
php bin/magento c:c
```

And second options :-

Go to your `app/etc` and open the `di.xml` file

Find this class `Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Symlink` and replace this `Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy`

**`THANKS`**.

Comment: ```Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Symlink``` and ```Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy``` already exist in the di.xml. Please which one is replacing which?

Comment: okay you only command

Comment: I ran the shell commands at the root of the magento directory, but did not work.

Comment: try this command `php bin/magento config:set web/secure/use_in_adminhtml 1`

Comment: When I run ```php bin/magento setup:upgrade``` I get PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Undefined class constant 'PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_KEY' in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\setup\src\Magento\Setup\Model\ConfigOptionsList.php:179
Stack trace:

Comment: When I run ```php bin/magento config:set web/secure/use_in_adminhtml 1``` I get PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Undefined class constant 'PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_KEY' in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\setup\src\Magento\Setup\Model\ConfigOptionsList.php:179

Comment: check your php version

Comment: check this link --- https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/305875/undefined-class-constant-pdomysql-attr-ssl-key-in-magento-setup-src-magento

Comment: My PHP version is 7.3.0. I got an error when I did this ```apt-get install php7.3-pdo php7.3-mysql```. Please, how am I supposed to use it on Windows?

Comment: you try above answer

Comment: Hello @Efosa check this link --- https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/316951/85907

Comment: thanks. open_basedir was already disabled in my php.ini and I am still having the problem. I now installed Magento 2.3.3 and did all that you suggested, yet no solution.